# How to update a Hilt provided singleton?

Tags: android, android-room, dagger-hilt

In my `AppModule` I have this:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideRoomDatabase(@ApplicationContext applicationContext: Context) : AppDatabase {
    return Room.databaseBuilder(
        applicationContext,
        AppDatabase::class.java, "testdatabase"
    )
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration() // only for development
        .build()
}
```

When a user signs out of my app, I delete the complete database:

```
database.close()
appContext.deleteDatabase("testdatabase")
```

If I then want to do anything with the database, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.
```

I understand the error - `provideRoomDatabase()` is a Singleton and therefore not executed again, after I have deleted the database. But how to fix this? How to tell Hilt that the `provideRoomDatabase()` code shall be executed once again?